# Using a log wrapper

Tags: c#, api, logging

I wanted to know if you suggest **(in your opinion)** using / building a logger wrapper such as [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) in order to use some kind of logger?
I presume that the use of such wrapper is to :
  1. Enable changing the logger library when needed.
  2. Make the API easier.
In the end does it really matters ? or the loggers are easy to use and do not need to simplify it or change the logger just like that.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is not clear.  Of course everything matters.  What do you mean by "the loggers are easy to use" and do not need to simplify?  Are you asking if a framework library is often changed?  Or if using native logging code is often changed.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: As i wrote in your opinion... did you use it ? is it smart

Comment: Yes it is good to use it.  First rule of programming - Don't rewrite, reuse.  That is: if someone else has written something that provides what you need, use that library if you can.  I recommend ELMAH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a wrapper logging library that uses health monitoring for asp.net sites and log4net for windows/console apps. This way the logging interface always stays the same and is easy to be used enterprise wide. In our case, we only wanted to log a few categories, error/debug/info etc. If you think you need to use some special features of a specific logging library, you may choose to implement it directly. If you are using any third party logging libraries, it may be good to have a wrapper because what if the support for that is stopped or you need to move to a better one later.

The decisions are always almost dependent on your specific needs and future plans.

Comment: quote : "health monitoring" - can you enplane please ?

Comment: you can configure sql stored procedure parameters for logging information into sql provider of health monitoring. You can also write custom providers. When you invoke log.LogError, you can control which logging sources get invoked. Take a look at this link for starters. http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this without a good specific reason to do it.

I think that it's not very likely you are going to want to change the logging library, unless you chose badly in the start.

What you probably would want is to use features specific to the logger you chose, but that means the wrapper is not really useful.